# Parse/Manipulate in awk

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I am new to `awk` programming. I have a question on manipulating text file, which is required to draw certain network based images in a visualization software (Circos http://circos.ca)

I have input data for which I want to manipulate values using `awk/grep/sed`.
There are 9 pairs (18 lines). 5 pairs (first 10 lines) are for "from=ABCB11", and 4 pairs (next 8 lines) are for "from =ABCC8". What I want is extract the value from the first line of the first pair and replace it in each alternate line of the rest of the other pairs.
So value for group-2 is 9 10, which should replace all the occurrence of value in group2.
The next value for group-2 is 28 29, which should be replaced by 9 10.

The stop should be determined by "from=name" which is "from=ABCB11". It is not necessary that the rows that have to captured expression from and replace in its next occurrence will belong to group-2 as in this instance. It could be group-3 or group-4 until group-10. So second set ("from =ABCC8") could have been belonged to group-4/5/6 not necessary group-2. It is just a coincidence here, but all group-num's will be same for each "from=" alternate line.

```
group-2 9 10 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=ACE,toid=11,use=1,z=1
group-3 0 1 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=ACE,toid=11,use=1,z=1
group-2 28 29 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=CHRM1,toid=114,use=1,z=1
group-5 0 1 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=CHRM1,toid=114,use=1,z=1
group-2 29 30 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=CHRM2,toid=115,use=1,z=1
group-5 1 2 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=CHRM2,toid=115,use=1,z=1
group-2 10 11 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=DRD2,toid=158,use=1,z=1
group-3 1 2 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=DRD2,toid=158,use=1,z=1
group-2 11 12 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=EGF,toid=164,use=1,z=1
group-3 2 3 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=EGF,toid=164,use=1,z=1
group-2 21 22 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ACE,toid=11,use=1,z=1
group-3 12 13 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ACE,toid=11,use=1,z=1
group-2 0 1 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1A,toid=21,use=1,z=1
group-1 0 1 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1A,toid=21,use=1,z=1
group-2 1 2 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1B,toid=22,use=1,z=1
group-1 1 2 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1B,toid=22,use=1,z=1
group-2 2 3 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1D,toid=23,use=1,z=1
group-1 2 3 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1D,toid=23,use=1,z=1
```

Below is the FINAL output,I am looking for:

```
group-2 9 10 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=ACE,toid=11,use=1,z=1
group-3 0 1 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=ACE,toid=11,use=1,z=1
group-2 9 10 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=CHRM1,toid=114,use=1,z=1
group-5 0 1 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=CHRM1,toid=114,use=1,z=1
group-2 9 10 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=CHRM2,toid=115,use=1,z=1
group-5 1 2 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=CHRM2,toid=115,use=1,z=1
group-2 9 10 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=DRD2,toid=158,use=1,z=1
group-3 1 2 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=DRD2,toid=158,use=1,z=1
group-2 9 10 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=EGF,toid=164,use=1,z=1
group-3 2 3 text color=black,from=ABCB11,fromid=4,order=2,thickness=3,to=EGF,toid=164,use=1,z=1
group-2 21 22 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ACE,toid=11,use=1,z=1
group-3 12 13 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ACE,toid=11,use=1,z=1
group-2 21 22 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1A,toid=21,use=1,z=1
group-1 0 1 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1A,toid=21,use=1,z=1
group-2 21 22 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1B,toid=22,use=1,z=1
group-1 1 2 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1B,toid=22,use=1,z=1
group-2 21 22 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1D,toid=23,use=1,z=1
group-1 2 3 text color=black,from=ABCC8,fromid=5,order=2,thickness=3,to=ADRA1D,toid=23,use=1,z=1
```

Also,this is just a sample data. So many pairs would have group-1,group-4,group-5 up to group 10. Here, only pairs from lesser groups are mentioned.

Basically, these are the modifications that should be seen while printing complete lines, until "from=ABCB11" ends, in each alternate line. Similarly for "from=ABCC8".

```
group-2 9 10
group-3 0 1
group-2 9 10
group-5 0 1
group-2 9 10
.........
.........
.........
```

Here is what I tried:

I want to loop through the lines until the value in "from=name" remains same,so that I can change all occurrences in each alternate line.Code:

```
awk -F, 'NR%2==1 {split($2,a,"="); print a[2]}' file.txt
```

The above code is able to extract the alternate lines and the "name" in "from=name".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like:

```
awk 'NR%2{if(p!=$2){v=$1; p=$2}$1=v}1' FS=, OFS=, file
```

This tests if `$2` has changed and substitutes `$1` on every odd line with the same value for every `$2`

---

### Added an explanation..

```
awk '
  NR%2 {            # On every line where NR (recordnr) mod 2 equals 1 (odd line)
    if(p!=$2) {     # If the variable p (previous) is different from the 2nd field then
      v=$1          # The new value v should become $1 (1st field)
      p=$2          # The new variable p becomes the current field 2
    }               #
    $1=v            # On every odd line field 1 becomes the previously set value
  }
  1                 # 1 means true. The default action is to print the record (line)
' FS=, OFS=, file   # Set the input and output field separators to a comma.
```

Comment: the command works awesome!! can you please explain the code if possible..what are variables :p,v and purpose of 1 at the end.Is it for checking the odd lines?

Comment: @Ron . Good to hear :) I added an explanation, hope it helps..

Comment: Quick question: which line specifies that "from=name" has changed,and it should not change the first alternate line of that,instead store it to compare with the alternate lines of that particular "from=name".

Comment: @Ron . `from=name` is the second field so that would be `if(p!=$2) {` it changes the first field or all grouped alternate lines with that particular `from=name`